# How can i use different selector with same name?

Tags: angular

For example, I have two module

> (1) module 'A'
>   - have a component 'list', selector 'list'
>
> (2) module 'B'
>   - also, have component 'list', selector 'list'

I wish to use both this 'list' component in my module's 'list' component is it possible?

If yes, then how can I use selector of those component?

Comment: you mean to say that you have three component named list, right?

Comment: yes one is my root and other two is external components, and selector is also list for whole.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If you want to use the list component from another list component and from different modules, you can do so by specifying `entryComponents` inside your Component or NgModule:

```
@Component({
  ...,
  entryComponents: [ AListComponent ]
})
export class BListComponent {}


or 


@NgModule({
  ...,
  entryComponents: [ AListComponent ]
})
export class ModuleB {}
```

**BListComponent Template**

```
   // You can then easily use & specify the AListComponent selector here
   <a-list-component></a-list-component>
```

---

> But if those modules are merged and imported on a root module like

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ AModule, BModule ]
})
export class RootModule {}
```

then on your **ModuleA**, you can just specify the component you need to export to be able to utilize it on other components

```
 @NgModule({
  ...,
  exports: [ AListComponent ]    // Export AListComponent to be utilized on BListComponent
})
export class ModuleA {}
```

**BListComponent Template**

```
<a-list-component></a-list-component>
```

Comment: The OP said that the selectors are all "list". But you use "a-list-component". Have the component selectors been remapped? Where exactly is that done/defined?

Answer (score -2):

```js
import {list} from '../location1/list';
import {list as list2} from '../location2/list';
```

Use this to avoid naming conflicts.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it's not I want.